# Returning elements of a row in a list using Scala

Tags: list, scala, set, row

I need to write a method that will return the contents of a particular row (index of it is inputted as method parameter). I have to use recursion and no loops.

So far I have attempted this uncompleted code (and I have no idea how to continue it):

```
class Sudoku(val grid: List[List[Int]]) {

   def r(r: Int): Set[Int] = {
   if (grid.isEmpty) Set()
   else 

  }
}
```

I also do not know how Set works. Any help would be really appreciated. PS: I am not asking for complete code, an algorithm explanation would be more than enough!

Comment: You're trying to solve too many problems at once. 1) What is a Set. 2) What is recursion. 3) The domain problem. The first problem you should learn how to solve though, is this: how to I solve a complex problem? And the answer to that is: break it up into sub-problems, and solve those seperately.

Comment: I know what recursion is... what do you mean by the domain problem?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the problem at hand, i.e. "return the contents of a particular row", independent of programming language.

Comment: Another problem is that this seems like a homework assignment. In general you would probably be getting better answer if you can show that you've made some effort trying to solve it before asking for solutions here. The question is also very unclear, as in what is meant by "a row in a list". If you have a list of lists, and we are assuming a grid context, I would assume that each of the inner lists represents a row in the grid. In such a case the solution would simply be to select the n'th list, but that sounds too simple, and as such there must be some context here that you haven't specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer to the literal interpretation of the question:

```
class Sudoku(val grid: List[List[Int]]) {
  def row(n: Int): List[Int] =
    if (grid.size > n) grid(n) else Nil
}
```

The apply method on `List`, here applied on the value `grid`, which can be written either `grid apply n`, or simply `grid(n)` returns the n'th element of the list. If that element does not exist (e.g. grid(1000000)), it throws an exception, therefore we check the size of the list first.

I have no idea why you should return a Set, but you could simple call `.toSet` on the result. A Set is a collection with distinct elements (each element only occurs once) with no guarantee of ordering.

I also don't know why you would need recursion for this, so I reckon the question is part of a larger problem.

Comment: Set() is the empty Set, as Nil (or List()) is the empty List.

Comment: `if (grid.size > n) grid(n).toSet else Set()`

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. I'm not quite sure what you want. Note that there is no such thing as a "first" element in a Set (since it is unordered).